# What do the different DOOM 4 antialiasing settings do and how do they impact performance relative to each other?

Tags: doom-2016

Here is what I am seeing, I have no clue what each of them mean:

- FXAA
- SMAA
- TAA (1TX)
- FXAA (1TX)
- SMAA (1TX)
- TSSAA (8TX)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

That list you're seeing is a list of different technologies for anti-aliasing the game. They're by no means exclusive to DOOM.

Different technologies perform anti-aliasing in different ways and thus achieve different results.
Usually the game lists them in order of less processing power consumption to more processing power consumption. The technology in the top is the one that requires less processing power and the one in the bottom is the one that requires the most processing power.
Generally the less processing power an anti-aliasing technology uses the less aliasing it reduces and/or introduces more blur or other defects in the image.
The more processing power it uses the more aliasing it reduces without introducing many defects to the image.

There are, however, a few exceptions to theses generic rules. I just gave them to use as a rule of thumb when you don't know what they mean.

Now let's go over a few of the technologies you mentioned:

- [FXAA - Fast approximate anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_approximate_anti-aliasing) - developed by Nvidia.

  - Pros: does not require large amounts of computing power and includes all pixels of the screen (even those showing transparent elements).
  - Cons: textures may not appear as sharp and must be applied before rendering the HUD elements
- [SMAA - Subpixel Morphological Anti-Aliasing](http://www.iryoku.com/smaa/downloads/SMAA-Enhanced-Subpixel-Morphological-Antialiasing.pdf) - it's a more efficient implementation of the traditional MLAA (Morphological Anti-Aliasing).
- [TAA - Temporal Anti-Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing) - a technique to prevent temporal aliasing which is caused by framrates being too low in comparison with moving objects in a scene.
- TSSAA - Temporal Super Sampling Anti-Aliasing - same as TAA but uses [supersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling) to achieve better visual results.

All of these technologies come in varying strengths indicated by their multiplier. The multiplier is the number with the TX in front of if. in TSSAA (8TX) the 8TX is the multiplier.
The higher the number the more processing power it will require and the better the results it will achieve.

For more on anti-aliasing please visit [Anti-Aliasing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing), [Spatial Anti-aliasing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) and [Anti-aliasing article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/different-antialiasing-options-mean-71544.html).

Comment: are you sure its transparency? transparency only reveals forum topics. [***Temporal*** its own wikipedia page.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasings)

Comment: @Timelord64 You are correct and I have corrected my answer. Thank you for point that out. There are a lot of technologies for computer graphics out there and I can only keep up with so many.

Comment: For future reference, to whoever downvoted my answer, we do not downvote an answer because part of it was incorrect. The correct thing to do is what @Timelord64 did and comment it or edit it. And I quote: "If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it." [Source](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: sorry to burst your bubble, but I downvoted, which is completely user discretionary.

Comment: I highly recommend you do not make the assumption that any user will follow that particular guideline. As another tip, asking about downvotes typically attracts more.

Comment: @Timelord64 Why would I not assume that the users follow Stack Exchange's guidelines? A lot of users are keen on flagging offtopic answers which is another guideline of this site (and just one of many examples). Why should we ignore that one? If I'm not supposed to ask about downvotes then how am I supposed to learn from my mistakes when people downvote without specifying why? I've seen very healthy improvements done to questions and answers that began with users asking about downvotes on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: perhaps other sites. On here, votes are viewed as completely discretionary. Perhaps because they are unmoderated. Post in meta about it if you disagree, but again, be prepared for downvoting

Comment: Voting is very much *not* discretionary. That said, the advice given to editors when touching up others' posts is "clarify meaning without changing it".

Comment: I'm resurrecting this topic for a simple question: what does the "T" in "8TX" mean? I would assume it's "times" but then that's already the meaning of "X"...

Comment: TSSAA is not really supersampling. It uses the last n frames (nTX) and superimpose them on the target frame to soften it. So in the 8TX version, it does not really calculate 8 times a larger frame before downscaling it.

Answer (score 3):

The T in TAA it means [Temporal Anti-Aliasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing).

Basically, every frames, the image is accumulated in an accumulation buffer and is merged with the current frame. This helps remove flickering (Temporal Aliasing).

TSSAA means Temporal Super Sampling Anti-Aliasing. This will compute Super Sampling Anti-Aliasing by using the accumulated frames. This will to not only reduce flickering, but will also reduce the aliasing of edges and textures. 8TX means that the aliasing is resolved using a pattern of 8 samples.

1. [Temporal Anti-Aliasing Super Sampling in Unreal Engine 4](http://advances.realtimerendering.com/s2014/#_HIGH-QUALITY_TEMPORAL_SUPERSAMPLING)
2. [High Quality Temporal Supersampling - Brian Karis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNQ47MY-Eo0)